# PowerShell commands for Outlook

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I want to create automated rules in Outlook by using PowerShell commands. I have tried for single user and can make folders by using the command, I want it to create folders for all users whoever mails me. Here are the codes which I have used for creating the single folders.

```
 $GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application" 
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(6) #‘olFolderInbox’
$olxEmailFolder.Name
$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders
ForEach ($Folder in $SubFolders) {
  $Folder.Folder
$sname= "Mohit"
ForEach($SubSubFolder in $Folder) {
   $fname= $SubSubFolder.Name
   if ($sname -ne $fname )
   {
   $comments = @' 

Script name: Create-Folder.ps1 
Created on: Monday, January 17, 2018 

Author: kundan 
Purpose: How can I use Windows Powershell to 
Create a New Folder in Microsoft Outlook? 
'@

#-----------------------------------------
------------ 
function Release-Ref ($ref) 
{ 
([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
[System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
} 

#----------------------------------------------------- 
$olFolderInbox = 6 
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
$n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$f = $n.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$nf = $f.Folders.Add("$sname") 
$a = Release-Ref($nf) 
$a = Release-Ref($f) 
$a = Release-Ref($n) 
$a = Release-Ref($o) 
   }
   else
   {
   echo "folder already  exist"
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The powershell is run once. If you want to create a folder for each sender name you need to develop a COM add-in for Outlook which is working with Outlook.

Looks like you need to create an add-in which can create a folder for a sender and then move an item received there. To get the job done you need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event of the Application class which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem , MeetingItem , or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the EntryIDCollection contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.

In the event handler you can get the sender name and create a corresponding folder. Then you can use the [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-move-method-outlook) method of the MailItem class which moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder.